# Query to compare data in table and data of same table XML file

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there any way to get data from xml file and compare data with database table
using query

Comment: There are many ways depending on the sort of technologies you're looking at using. Personally I'd load both into an application and compare but we're going to need some more guidance to help you. What sort of data types are involved? Are you just using SQl or can you use C#/.NET?

Comment: Query to use in sql server 
I want to know how to compare retrieved data with table data

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the XML file into a table which contains a column of XML type.

E.g.

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeXMLTable](
    [SomeXMLColumn] [xml] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [SomeXMLTable]
           ([SomeXMLColumn])
     VALUES
        ('<root>
        <node1>1</node1>
        <node2>2</node2>
        <node3>3</node3>
        </root>')
```

Once you have that,
you can extract the values from the xml and compare it with any table that holds the corresponding value.

```
SELECT 
SomeXMLColumn.value('(/root/node1)[1]', 'varchar(max)' ) as Node1Value,
SomeXMLColumn.value('(/root/node2)[1]', 'varchar(max)' ) as Node2Value,
SomeXMLColumn.value('(/root/node3)[1]', 'varchar(max)' ) as Node3Value
FROM   SomeXMLTable
```